# How to add reference to ocx in delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, activex, ocx

I have a bpl package in delphi 2010. That have two required files (rtl.dcp and vcl.dcp).

I create an ActiveX ocx in my project and move all pas files to that. I cannot build that because "rtl.dcp and vcl.dcp" is not required to that. I want to add reference to ActiveX Project or export bpl project to ocx.
How to?

Comment: Why are you using runtime packages?

Comment: because i am using rtl and vcl references in bpl project.and i want to buil this to ocx and use this to other programming language.i have a delphi project.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from adding references to the `rtl` and `vcl` packages to your OCX project.  What is the real problem?

Comment: i cannot add reference in ocx project. i am right click ocx project an "add reference" menu not found

Comment: Why do you want to use runtime packages? I get the feeling that really understand what you are doing.

Comment: @David, in a package project, you specify which run-time packages to use on the package's "requires" list. For any other kind of project, there is no such "requires" list. Instead, the list of run-time packages to use is specified elsewhere. I assume an OCX is just a DLL project, and so the list of packages is controlled in the same place as for DLLs and EXEs, wherever that is.

Comment: @RobKennedy That's right. My point is that I wonder if the user really wants to use runtime packages, because they impose a load time linking dependency that is hard to meet for an in-proc COM server.